# Node js : Async or Sync

Tags: node.js

I am working on a project where 4 different color assigned for 4 different order in bar . `isCart : 4` mean order is not completed/cancelled. Once 4 color are occupied will start assigning default color to upcoming order. Once that order in completed or cancelled then that assigned color is free and start assign to next upcoming order.i am facing an issue where sometime color is repeating for different user in same bar.
here is my logic:

```
let colorCode: string = await this.common.orderColorCode(updateStatus.barId,
  checkoutSessionData.orderId);

public async orderColorCode(barId: string, orderId: string) {
  console.log(barId + ' barId');
  console.log(orderId + ' orderId');
  let orderedColorCode = await this.itemOrderService.findOneCart(
    { barId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(barId), colorCode: { $ne: constants.defaultColor }, "isCart": 4 },
    { _id: 0, colorCode: 1 }, { colorCode: 1 }, 0);

  const usedColorCode = orderedColorCode.map(function (obj) {
    return obj.colorCode;
  });
  console.log(usedColorCode + ' Used Color code');
  var pendingColorCode = constants.colorCode.filter(function (item) {
    return usedColorCode.indexOf(item) === -1;
  });
  console.log(pendingColorCode + ' pending Color code');
  let colorCode = (pendingColorCode.length === 0) ? constants.defaultColor : pendingColorCode[0];
  console.log(colorCode + ' Color code----------');
  const updateColorCode = await this.itemOrderService.updateColorCodeOrderId({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(orderId) }, colorCode);
  return colorCode;
}
```

Comment: May I ask for values of these variables - `usedColorCode`, and `pendingColorCode`. Might help me understand what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: used color will be like : ['#3CB44B','#4363D8'], is this color are already used in other pending orders.pending color will be like this ['#911EB4','#E6194B'] these color are free to use..colorCode: ['#3CB44B','#4363D8','#911EB4','#E6194B'] this is my constant color

Comment: i think issue is multiple request hit at same time..

Comment: is anyone know to block previous request once current one is completed??